# Computed property is not getting updated

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to built some authentication within my EmberJS application, so after the user has logged in, i save the user id and a token using local storage. This works as planned, i have then build a set up computed properties for helping determine if a players has logged in.

```
MyApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend

  currentUser: (->
    @AuthManager.get('apiKey.user')
  ).property('AuthManager.apiKey')

  isAuthenticated: (->
    @AuthManager.isAuthenticated
  ).property('AuthManager.apiKey')
```

As you can see it just fetch the data from my AuthManager. Now my big problem is that these computed properties does not update, even tho the apiKey changes. So i tried to debug it.

```
  currentUser: (->
    @AuthManager.get('apiKey.user')
  ).property('AuthManager.apiKey')

  isAuthenticated: (->
    #@AuthManager.isAuthenticated
    console.log "Something changed to " + @get('AuthManager.apiKey.accessToken')

    self = @
    setInterval ->
      console.log self.get('AuthManager.apiKey.accessToken')
    , 1000
  ).property('AuthManager.apiKey.accessToken')
```

First the apiKey is undefined, but after the user is loaded, the apiKeys is set, but property fails to see this change.

This is the output of the code.

[image]

As you can see the apiKeys changes, but "Something changed to" is only printed once?

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is because the `AuthManager` starts with a capital letter, when you use `@set('AuthManager.accessToken', ...)` ember lookup the a global path, like `window.AuthManager.accessToken` instead of `controllerInstance.AuthManager.accessToken` so refactor your code to use just `authManager`.

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) trigger several times, because it's a timer that executes repeatedly until `clearInterval` is called, with the returned id from `setInterval`

Comment: Thank you so much, please accept my first born as a reward! Been stuck on this all day.